# Python smtp is send email but its not delivered

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to send email using smtp. The script seems to work fine with gmail and Outlook but when i try to send via other smtp server its not working. (shows no error but the email is not delivered, i have checked spam folder too). I have tried to connect and send mail using third party app and they are working with same credential.

The code is

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

username = "" 
password = "" 
From = username
Subject = 'Test'
#list of emails and their first name
names = ['']
emails = ['']



server = smtplib.SMTP('mafraproducoes.com.br', 587)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
#server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = username
msg['To'] = names[0]
msg['Subject'] = Subject
text = '''
Hello {},
    This is bulk mailing test!
'''.format(names[0])
msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain'))
message = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(username, emails[0], message)
print('Mail sent to', emails[0])

server.quit()
print('All emails sent successfully!')
```

The debug features shows following message.

```
send: 'ehlo [127.0.0.1]\r\n'
reply: b'250-srv178.prodns.com.br Hello [127.0.0.1] [27.60.54.90]\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 52428800\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPE_CONNECT\r\n'
reply: b'250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN\r\n'
reply: b'250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'250 HELP\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'srv178.prodns.com.br Hello [127.0.0.1] [27.60.54.90]\nSIZE 52428800\n8BITMIME\nPIPELINING\nPIPE_CONNECT\nAUTH PLAIN LOGIN\nSTARTTLS\nHELP'
send: 'AUTH PLAIN (removed auth token) =\r\n'
reply: b'235 Authentication succeeded\r\n'
reply: retcode (235); Msg: b'Authentication succeeded'
send: 'mail FROM:(removed from) size=390\r\n'
reply: b'250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK'
send: 'rcpt TO:(removed to) \r\n'
reply: b'250 Accepted\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'Accepted'
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: b'354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: b'Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself'
data: (354, b'Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself')
send: b'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=============== (probably token) =="\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nFrom: (from) \r\nTo: max\r\nSubject: Test\r\n\r\n--===============( probably token) ==\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n\r\nHello max,\r\n    This is bulk mailing test!\r\n\r\n--=============== (probably token) ==--\r\n.\r\n'
reply: b'250 OK id=1lhChJ-002eHo-8l\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK id=1lhChJ-002eHo-8l'
data: (250, b'OK id=1lhChJ-002eHo-8l')
Mail sent to 
send: 'quit\r\n'
reply: b'221 srv178.prodns.com.br closing connection\r\n'
reply: retcode (221); Msg: b'srv178.prodns.com.br closing connection'
All emails sent successfully!

[Program finished]
```

Comment: if you  are able to send email using other servers then no issue with your code. it will be mostly limitation with the server it is not able to send

Comment: Try to   test smtp conneion by connecting to smtp server and send email using telnet

Comment: I have tried telnet and it's working fine